# How to remove the last string in an array element using parameters of another method named removeLast()

Tags: java, netbeans

Here is the question of exercise and my code:

Create the method public static void removeLast(ArrayList strings) in the exercise template. The method should remove the last value in the list it receives as a parameter. If the list is empty, the method does nothing.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Try your method in here
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayList.add("First");
    arrayList.add("Second");
    arrayList.add("Third");
    System.out.println(arrayList);
    removeLast(arrayList);
    System.out.println(arrayList);
}

public static void removeLast(ArrayList<String> strings) {
    strings.remove("Second");
    strings.remove("Third");
}
```

The sample output should look similar to the following:

```
[First, Second, Third]
[First]
```

What does the exercise mean by if the list is empty, the method does nothing?

I also keep getting error from local test saying the following:

**removeLast method should remove the last element of the list.**

Could someone help please?

Comment: 1) I would assume that your professor has code that executes your implementation of `removeLast` several times with different contents of the ArrayList. The message "removeLast method should remove the last element of the list" means the result(s) returned by your program didn't match what the professor expected.

Comment: 2) You were asked to remove the last element of the list, but you removed the last two.  3) You also "hard coded" the values to be removed.  You are to code `removeLast` so that it will remove the last element regardless of the values it contains.

Comment: 4)  An array or `Collection` is empty when it contains no elements.  You need to test if `strings` is empty. If it is empty, `return;` instead of attempting to delete the last element.  [ArrayList API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer, is there a mathematical or linear way to describe if a certain string array list is empty or not? with out using .isEmpty () method? Besides, how can I return when the method is a void type? I thought void method types cannot return values

Comment: Well,  you could use `.size()` and compare it to zero:  `if (strings.size() == 0)`, e.g. You're right: `void` return type means the method cannot return a value. But, you are being passed (a copy of) the reference to the ArrayList to be modified. So, when you change the contents of the list, it is changed in the calling method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"If the list is empty, the method does nothing" --> Check if the list is empty or not, if empty just return nothing , else delete last element(as per your requirement)

Example:

```
public static void removeLast(ArrayList<String> strings) {
        
        if( (strings.isEmpty())) {
         return;
        } 
        else {
            strings.remove(strings.size()-1);
            
        }
        
    
    }
```

Comment: Is there a mathematical way to describe if a string is empty or not using null as a replacement? Instead of using .isEmpty() method, can it be done in a simpler way rather than a-ready-function method?

Comment: Using the API as the creators of the class intended is the simplest way. If the creators of a class restricted access to instance variables, as they should, attempting to avoid a method call is an attempt to break encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

you can first simply check list is empty of not if it is not empty than you can call `size()` methos it give last `index number` of list and simply you can call `remove(int)` method to remove last element.

```
 public static void removeLast(ArrayList<String> strings) {

   if(strings.isEmpty()) {

   } else {
      strings.remove(strings.size()-1);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for assistance, is there a mathematical or linear way to solve the problem instead of the method .isEmpty? Can I use null as a replacement? Or does that not work?

Comment: No, using `null` won't work.  In an expression such as `x == null` , `x` is a reference type, `null` is a reference value.  The expression tests whether `x` exists or not. An `ArrayList` can exist, therefore not `null`, and still be empty.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mathematical way to check if arrayList is empty or not.
a. Either you have to check with method isEmpty() [or]
b. check with array list size is greater than zero.

In application programming you have to check if array list is NOT NULL and the list is NOT EMPTY.

Comment: @belinyom, as this answer suggests, you may have to guard against the possibility that your method will be passed a `null` reference. You, if working independently, or possibly in consultation with others, if working with a team ,might have to decide how your method should react if `args == null`.  One possibility is to return. Another possibility is to throw an exception.